# How do I enable Fingerprint scanning on my HP Elitebook

Tags: hp, fingerprint-reader

[screenshot of my connected devices using lsusb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDzG2.png)

How do i setup fingerprint for ubuntu on my machine

Comment: OS & release details are probably the starting point, what are you running?   *Text is easier to read rather than a picture of text, are you using a Server system (*thus the photograph of text not copy/pasted into your question?*)

Comment: Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05c8:0396 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP IR Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:080b Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 138a:0092 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Here's the text.

I'm currently running Ubuntu 22.04

@guiverc

Comment: Please add additional details to your question; as that is what is answered (*comments get deleted once dealt with; largely intended for queries of the original poster, and be complete; Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server? Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop etc.*)